# Managing multiple filters in geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, filters

In the interactive JavaScript console of geth, I have added some JS snippets(filters) through the loadScript() command and I need to remove/stop executing those filters. Is there any way to do this without restarting the geth instance?

I have the following filters loaded. None of them contain a watch function:

> 1. A filter to mine only when there are pending transactions.
> 2. A filter to check **if** a transaction was directed to a specific account and print some details.

Is there a way to identify and start/stop these filters?

Comment: I wish you had elaborated how /what is your filter about, it would have helped,however I have given and answer @varm

Comment: Added more details @TheNeoNoirDeveloper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,You could use the stopWatching() function to each of the filters when you want them to stop functioning.

```
var filter = <your filter code>;
//now you want to stop them being functional
 filter.stopWatching();
```

Will do what you want.

Running `eth.filter()` command on the JavaScript console gives a list of all the filters along with the unique filterIDs. The `stopWatching()` function can be invoked with each of those filterIDs to disable that filter.

Comment: Thank you. But my filters do not have a watch function. Even if there was a watch function, how would I identify each filter and stop it if there are multiple filters?

Comment: Even if you don't have a watch associated, the stopWatching() would invalidate your filter @varm. And each filter has a property called filterId, much like an address. For a developer he could create a map of filters and run through each of them and invoke stopWatching() on each to make them invalidate.

Comment: Updated the answer @varm and see my earlier comment on filter id

Comment: Is there any command/option to set/get the filterID?